# Modeling Users, Things, and Things voted or scored by users?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, orm, ado.net, data-modeling

I'm new to entity framework and data modeling.

Problem:

I have user objects and thing objects, my confusion beings once a user "votes" on the thing?
On the EF side I think I understand the "many to many association" and on the db side I think I understand a "user_thing table" which would hold the primary keys for user and thing. My problem is once a user votes on a thing it is now unique to that user. (not the same as the thing not voted on or the thing some other user voted on). How do it persist or model this? Do  I create a new table for each user that only holds the things voted on? Do I create a new object with some kind of inheritance from my thing object that has a many to one association with the user? I know the answer to this is out there considering so many websites use voting, scoring, liking, etc...Even just a push in the right direction would be most appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Your schema looks like this:

```
User
UserId (Primary Key)
Name 
(etc)

Thing
ThingId (Primary Key)
Name
(etc)

UserThingVote
UserId
ThingId
--Has **composite** primary key on UserId, ThingId
```

I think your confusion is in this statement:

> My problem is once a user votes on a thing it is now unique to that user

That is not true because the UserThing table has a composite primary key - not a PK on UserId. Now, you can have many records in the UserThingVote table. Each UserId,ThingId combination must be unique.

You can insert into the UserThing table in EF just like you insert into any other table. You should also set up foreign key relationships between the UserThingVote table and the User and Thing table. That will make object traversal in EF much easier.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you solve your question, please mark it as accepted. That will give me points and make it more likely that other's will answer your questions next time.